Delete on condition within a flattened JSON by using a jolt spec
Within a flattened JSON, I would like to delete all information related to an attribute as soon as the ".....values[0].value"  is an empty string ("").
INPUT :
{
  "p-unit.myProduct.attributes[0].height.identifier": "height",
  "p-unit.myProduct.attributes[0].height.type": "int",
  "p-unit.myProduct.attributes[0].height.values[0].value": "",
  "p-unit.myProduct.attributes[0].height.values[0].uom.value": "cm",
  "p-unit.myProduct.attributes[1].width.identifier": "width",
  "p-unit.myProduct.attributes[1].width.type": "int",
  "p-unit.myProduct.attributes[1].width.values[0].value": "",
  "p-unit.myProduct.attributes[1].width.values[0].uom.value": "cm",
  "p-unit.myProduct.attributes[2].minimum.identifier": "minimum",
  "p-unit.myProduct.attributes[2].minimum.type": "int",
  "p-unit.myProduct.attributes[2].minimum.values[0].value": "15",
  "p-unit.myProduct.attributes[2].minimum.values[0].uom.value": "cm"
}

DESIRED OUTPUT :
{
  "p-unit.myProduct.attributes[2].minimum.identifier": "minimum",
  "p-unit.myProduct.attributes[2].minimum.type": "int",
  "p-unit.myProduct.attributes[2].minimum.values[0].value": "15",
  "p-unit.myProduct.attributes[2].minimum.values[0].uom.value": "cm"
}

As you can see, only the attribute "minimum" should remain, because it is the only one, which provides a value (15).
Thanks in advance for your help.

The crucial issue is determining the correct common factors to group such as by
p-unit.myProduct.attributes[, after first ] and after last .
as in the following transformation :
[
  {//implement groupings
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "p-unit.myProduct.attributes\\[*\\]*\\.*": ["&(0,1).&(0,3)", "&(0,1).&"]
    }
  },
  {//accumulate the attributes under the nodes with key of "" vs non-"" 
   //those are composed through use of the values of "values[0].value" attributes
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "p-unit*": "&1.@(1,values\\[0\\]\\.value).&"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "": {//get rid of empty values
          "": ""
        },
        "*": ""//while keeping the rest
      }
    }
  }
]

By the 1st spec, we derive the "values[0].value" attributes along while keeping the original attributes which start with p-unit literals :
{
  "0" : {
    "identifier" : "height",
    "p-unit.myProduct.attributes[0].height.identifier" : "height",
    "type" : "int",
    "p-unit.myProduct.attributes[0].height.type" : "int",
    "values[0].value" : "",
    "p-unit.myProduct.attributes[0].height.values[0].value" : "",
    "values[0].uom.value" : "cm",
    "p-unit.myProduct.attributes[0].height.values[0].uom.value" : "cm"
  },
  "1" : {
    "identifier" : "width",
    "p-unit.myProduct.attributes[1].width.identifier" : "width",
    "type" : "int",
    "p-unit.myProduct.attributes[1].width.type" : "int",
    "values[0].value" : "",
    "p-unit.myProduct.attributes[1].width.values[0].value" : "",
    "values[0].uom.value" : "cm",
    "p-unit.myProduct.attributes[1].width.values[0].uom.value" : "cm"
  },
  "2" : {
    "identifier" : "minimum",
    "p-unit.myProduct.attributes[2].minimum.identifier" : "minimum",
    "type" : "int",
    "p-unit.myProduct.attributes[2].minimum.type" : "int",
    "values[0].value" : "15",
    "p-unit.myProduct.attributes[2].minimum.values[0].value" : "15",
    "values[0].uom.value" : "cm",
    "p-unit.myProduct.attributes[2].minimum.values[0].uom.value" : "cm"
  }
}

By the 2nd spec, we have the keys of empty strings ("") vs. others to be prepared to be filtering out :
{
  "0" : {
    "" : {
      "p-unit.myProduct.attributes[0].height.identifier" : "height",
      "p-unit.myProduct.attributes[0].height.type" : "int",
      "p-unit.myProduct.attributes[0].height.values[0].value" : "",
      "p-unit.myProduct.attributes[0].height.values[0].uom.value" : "cm"
    }
  },
  "1" : {
    "" : {
      "p-unit.myProduct.attributes[1].width.identifier" : "width",
      "p-unit.myProduct.attributes[1].width.type" : "int",
      "p-unit.myProduct.attributes[1].width.values[0].value" : "",
      "p-unit.myProduct.attributes[1].width.values[0].uom.value" : "cm"
    }
  },
  "2" : {
    "15" : {
      "p-unit.myProduct.attributes[2].minimum.identifier" : "minimum",
      "p-unit.myProduct.attributes[2].minimum.type" : "int",
      "p-unit.myProduct.attributes[2].minimum.values[0].value" : "15",
      "p-unit.myProduct.attributes[2].minimum.values[0].uom.value" : "cm"
    }
  }
}

the demo on the site Jolt Transform Demo Using v0.1.1 is :


Hello Barbaros, what an amazing and creative approach. Thank you so much.

Hello Katja, enjoy :)
